# БЭМ и связи между блоками на уровне именования классов

Tags: бэм

Могу ли я считать,что в данном скриншоте некоторые классы, показывающие связь между блоками и делающими все блоки элементами является избыточным и так можно не делать? http://prntscr.com/kz8zwa

Или в данном скриншоте сделано все правильно и так должно быть?

К примеру исходя из скриншота nav является элементом дочерним main-navigation, можно ли было обойтись просто классом для nav main-navigation не добавляя класс указывающий на принадлежность mobile-header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, избыточно.

Элемент — необязательный компонент блока. Не у всех блоков должны быть элементы.

Пример

```
<!-- Блок `search-form` -->
<div class="search-form">
    <!-- Блок `input` -->
    <input class="input">

    <!-- Блок `button` -->
    <button class="button">Найти</button>
</div>
```

- Элементы можно вкладывать друг в друга.
- Допустима любая вложенность элементов.
- Элемент — всегда часть блока, а не другого элемента. Это означает,
  что в названии элементов нельзя прописывать иерархию вида
  block__elem1__elem2.

Из документации:

> https://ru.bem.info/methodology/quick-start/

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ